# PL/SQL: Check if there is sufficient space in schema before creating table

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I'm using a procedure which creates a table using a heavy query (running ~1 hr). Query is something like 'select * from table', and the columns in the table can change.
Oftentimes it turns out that there is no free space in schema to create the table, so I get an exception, the time is spent in vain and I need to do the same calculations once again.

The error I get:

> ORA-01536: space quota exceeded for tablespace 
>   ORA-06512: at "UPDATE_REPORT", line 37

What I would want to do:
- Store query's results in temporary segment in a cursor;
- Try to create table using cursor. In case of exception (not enough space), drop a special space-holding table to free table space in schema;
- Try to create the table again from cursor.

I tried to solve this using dynamic SQL, but it leads to overcomplications while the problem seems to have a simple solution. And the main problem I faced is that there is no evident way to create a table using cursor.

Is there any simple solution I somehow missed out? Maybe cursor are the wrong way to work this out?

Comment: This sounds like a design problem.  Why do you have to create this table repeatedly?  One option is to use an external table and write the query results to that.  It will still take up disk space but by the OS, not the database.  You can then check the db size, and do a "select into.." from the external table.

Comment: Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button below the tags and include information about the error you're getting - ORA- number and text. Thanks.

Comment: The reason for re-creating is that it is a table with analytical data in data laboratory, the requirements change often, so it is the easiest way to provide flexibility and quick change.

Comment: I'm not sure if external table will work. Its size is about 4 GB, and I suppose it will take more time to export the table. But anyway thanks for the advice, it could be very useful in some tasks.

Comment: why materialized view doesn't work ?

Comment: @Moudiz Thanks for advice, I'll try this, should be the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I would want to do: - Store query's results in temporary segment in a cursor; - Try to create table using cursor. In case of exception (not enough space), drop a special space-holding table to free table space in schema; - Try to create the table again from cursor.

Don't go through the trouble.  Just tell Oracle not to die because of space issues.

You can make your session "resumable" so that, rather than giving you an error when you run out of space, Oracle will suspend your session until the problem is corrected (and then continue on automatically).

Assuming you have all the permissions you need (notably, `GRANT RESUMABLE TO yourschema`), you enable it like this:

```
alter session enable resumable timeout 1800 name 'your process name, can be anything';
```

The `1800` number is in seconds, giving your DBA's 30 minutes to fix the problem before your session times out.  The "my process" will show up in `V$RESUMABLE` for use in queries and automated alerts.

Your DBAs can monitor `V$RESUMABLE` and/or you can create a schema-level database trigger on the `AFTER SUSPEND` event to fire off an e-mail to them when they need to jump in.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Hope it would work for me. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Two things I can think of:

- let the database do the dirty job

  - a.k.a. *enjoy your DBA job, simply by looking at Oracle administering itself*
  - how? let tablespace **autoextend**
- grant *unlimited quota* on that tablespace to user

Here's how (connected as a privileged user):

```
SQL> select file_name, tablespace_name From dba_data_files;

FILE_NAME                                        TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------------------------ -----------------------------
C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\USERS.DBF      USERS
C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\SYSAUX.DBF     SYSAUX
C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\UNDOTBS1.DBF   UNDOTBS1
C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\SYSTEM.DBF     SYSTEM

SQL> alter database datafile 'C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\USERS.DBF'
  2  autoextend on
  3  maxsize unlimited;

Database altered.

SQL> alter user scott quota unlimited on users;

User altered.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @OldProgrammer - this is a design problem. Dropping and re-creating tables is an anti-pattern.

It's not clear what exact problem you're trying to solve, but a more sensible approach might be:

1. Create the table once. Use INITIAL EXTENT parameter to ensure that the table has all the space it needs (you may have to run some queries to establish what that figure should be).
2. Check with your DBA that the tablespace is set to AUTOEXTEND, in case there are rogue result sets which exceed your calculations. Maybe negotiate more tablespace quota for the schema owner.
3. Populate the table once.
4. Before subsequent runs, TRUNCATE the table using the REUSE STORAGE clause to hold on to the assigned space.